# SphinxQL match equivalent of MySQL LIKE %searchterm%

Tags: sphinx, manticore-search

In my MySQL database I have this result querying my data:

```
mysql> select count(*) from emails where email like '%johndoe%';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|      102 |
+----------+
1 row in set (15.50 sec)
```

My data is indexed under Sphinx (Manticore Search actually) with `min_word_len = 1`. Now, when I search with SphinxQL I get only partial results:

```
mysql> SELECT count(*) FROM search1 WHERE MATCH('@email johndoe') LIMIT 1000 OPTION max_matches=1000;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|       16 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any idea how to match the results MySQL give me? I tried `SPH_MATCH_ANY` and `SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED` with the sphinxapi, same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's mainly due to whole word matching. Sphinx matches whole words. 
With 'words' defined as per charset_table http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-charset-table.html

ie `MATCH('@email johndoe')` is only matching addresses with `johndoe` in them as a **word**. default charset_table keeps `.` `-` and `@` (common in emails!) all as **separators** so would match `johndoe@domain.com` or `email@johndoe.com`, but NOT `email@myjohndoe.com`, the word being indexed is `myjohndoe` not `johndoe`

Whereas mysql 'LIKE' will happy match part words. eg `email like '%johndoe%'` would `johndoesmith@domain.com`, `johndoes555@domain.com` and `555@johndoes.com`or whatever. Its a pure substring match.

---

In short might want to tweak `charset_table`. could  `.` `-` and `@` all be word chars, so email would be whole word.

---

alternatively might just enable part word matching with  `min_infix_len`. 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-min-infix-len

then could do `MATCH('@email *johndoe*')` which would get much closer results.

---

complementary to `min_infix_len` would be `expand_keywords` http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-expand-keywords

then the * wildcards would be added automatically, so could go back to `MATCH('@email johndoe')`